# DevOps : Non-Interactive login in new DevOps(VSTS) not working getting error 'TF30063: You are not authorized to access

Tags: azure-devops, devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I am trying to connect to Azure DevOps previously known as VSTS using c#. I want to connect to it without the login screen of azure DevOps. I am currently trying the following code but some how it is not working

```
        NetworkCredential netCred = new NetworkCredential("test@hotmail.com", "test");
        Uri tfsuri = new Uri("https://dev.azure.com/test10");
        VssBasicCredential bsCred = new VssBasicCredential(netCred);
        VssCredentials vssCred = new VssClientCredentials(bsCred);

        TfsTeamProjectCollection collection = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(tfsuri, vssCred);

        collection.Authenticate();

        var witClient = collection.GetClient<ProjectHttpClient>();
        var listOfProjects = witClient.GetProjects().Result;
```

libraries I am using

```
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Core.WebApi;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Client;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Operations;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.WebApi;
```

The code prompts a login screen, on which if I enter the password the auth still does not work. I dont want the login screen to appear and only want to connect with the username and password.

With alternate credentials this method is working but it is not my requirement and I can not use alternate credentials.

I have tried following the samples from the [official site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/client-libraries/samples?view=vsts) but no solution is working for the new DevOps.

Any Solution how can I authenticate with usernanme/password in the new DevOps without the login screen

Answer (score 8):

The class `TfsTeamProjectCollection` is from the old .Net libraries, try the new Azure DevOps [.Net libraries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/concepts/dotnet-client-libraries?view=vsts), and you can authenticate in a few ways:

**NTLM**

The most basic one is constructing a VssCredentials instance with no parameter at all and what you’ll be using is simply put integrated authentication / NTLM:

```
var visualStudioServicesConnection = new VssConnection(new Uri(baseUri), new VssCredentials());
```

**Basic Authentication**

VSTS and TFS also provide means to utilize Basic authentication (HTTP AUTH) which you need to create and enable first ([see VSTS guidelines](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/integrate/get-started/auth/overview)) and once you’ve done so, you can use them via the API like this:

```
var visualStudioServicesConnection = new VssConnection(new Uri(baseUri), new VssBasicCredential(username, password));
```

**Personal Access Tokens**

Next up are Personal Access Tokens (PAT) which you can [easily create](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/get-started/setup/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate) following the VSTS guidelines and those PATs are a means of authenticating separately from your actual credentials with a fine-grained & per access token scopes of security. Simply put it allows you to create a PAT for every use-case or even application and thereby enabling a secure and clearly separated way of giving an application or 3rd party access to your VSTS or TFS system on your behalf.

To use these via the API, you use the exact same mechanism as via Basic Authentication but you simply don’t provide any username (well – an empty one to be precise), and the PAT itself is used as the password:

```
var visualStudioServicesConnection = new VssConnection(new Uri(baseUri), new VssBasicCredential(string.Empty, pat));
```

**Visual Studio Sign-in Prompt**

Moreover, another way of authenticating is using the standard VS Sign-In prompt which is similarly easy and exposed via the [VssClientCredentials](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.services.client.vssclientcredentials(v=vs.120).aspx) class:

```
var visualStudioServicesConnection = new VssConnection(new Uri(baseUri), new VssClientCredentials());
```

**OAuth Authentication**

[OAuth](http://oauth.net/) is a widely used but a slightly more tedious authorization protocol to implement but luckily there’s a thorough sample application available at CodePlex specifically for VSTS / VSO (which also works for on-premises).

Once you have the corresponding access token, you can use it to VSTS / TFS utilizing the [VssOAuthCredential](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.services.client.vssoauthcredential(v=vs.120).aspx) class:

```
var visualStudioServicesConnection = new VssConnection(new Uri(baseUri), new VssOAuthCredential(accessToken));
```

**Azure Active Directory Authentication**

Last but not least you can utilize Azure Active Directory identities to authenticate against a VSTS or TFS system via the VssAadCredential class:

```
var visualStudioServicesConnection = new VssConnection(new Uri(baseUri), new VssAadCredential(username, password));
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I want to use Basic Authentication but if I put my email and password in the VssBasicCredential(username, password). It does not authenticate the connection.  I dont want to use alternate credentials for this

Comment: what do you mean not authenticate the connection, do you get an error?

Comment: I tired that 
            VssConnection connection = new VssConnection(tfsuri, new VssBasicCredential(netCred));             WorkItemTrackingHttpClient witClient = connection.GetClient<WorkItemTrackingHttpClient>(); and I get the following error rosoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.VssUnauthorizedException: 'VS30063: You are not authorized to access https://dev.azure.com.'

Comment: Did you try without `netCred`, just put strings?

Comment: (new Uri(baseUri), new VssBasicCredential("test@hotmail.com", "test")) i get same error

Comment: what do you mean by "HTTP AUTH) which you need to create and enable first" I am beginner in DevOps and auth and sorry I dont understand it

Comment: In second thought I not sure azure devops support basic, maybe only TFS, try to check the contractors of `VssCredentials`.